# How to assign a constant to a value on all rows, if that value is adjacent to some value on any row

Tags: oracle

I have data like this (STATUS, and NAME are the column headers):

```
STATUS      NAME
ACTIVE      A1
INACTIVE    A1
INACTIVE    B1
INACTIVE    B1
```

I want to include a CUSTOM field that returns a constant for a particular NAME  value, if that NAME value is adjacent to a specific STATUS value on any row in the data:

```
CUSTOM      STATUS      NAME
ACTIVE      INACTIVE    A1
ACTIVE      ACTIVE      A1
INACTIVE    INACTIVE    B1
INACTIVE    INACTIVE    B1
```

Because `NAME = A1` had a `STATUS` of `ACTIVE` in row 2 above, I want `CUSTOM` to show `ACTIVE` for all rows tied to the `NAME = A1`. I tried this for the CUSTOM field:

```
case when NAME in (select NAME from SOURCE where STATUS='ACTIVE') then 'ACTIVE' else 'INACTIVE' end CUSTOM
```

But the above is still reflecting the same as STATUS on any given row.

Comment: In an RDBMS there is no concept of "above" or "below" per se. However, some RDBMSes implement the LEAD and LAG window functions which you can use for geting the immediately next or prior rows sorted by some criteria. However, there's no possible sorting criteria in your example: you'd need an ID, or a timestamp, or something similar you can sort by.

Comment: At this point you don't need much knowledge to just accept the fact that rows in a table have no inherent order. When returning them without specifying any order, they are sorted arbitrarily and, in general, unpredictably. Consequently, if you want to tell an adjacent row from a non-adjacent one, there must be an additional attribute in your example to specify the row order that makes sense for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the explanation in the question, it seems that you don't really care about the ordering but you want to know if for the same `name` there is at least one row with `status = 'ACTIVE'`.

This can be done with a window function, using `OVER (PARTITION BY name)`. The `CASE` expression has a default of `NULL` so `MAX()` will return null if there is no such value. The final `COALESCE()` will convert those nulls to `'INACTIVE'`:

```
SELECT 
    status, name,
    COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'ACTIVE' THEN status END) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY name), 
             'INACTIVE') AS custom
FROM
    table_name ;
```

Comment: sorry for late acceptance. am new to stackexchange.

Comment: @JJBee no worries. There is no threshold for accepting an answer ;) You can even unaccept later and accept another answer, if you feel it has helped you more.

Answer (score 0):

This will return your desired results and will also work if you have more than the 2 example rows given...if you want to return ACTIVE if any of the other rows are ACTIVE. I'm not sure if this meets your requirements or if you are looking for a solution that will evaluate only the closest row.

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ([status] varchar(10), [name] varchar(2))

INSERT INTO #temptable VALUES ('ACTIVE','A1')
INSERT INTO #temptable VALUES ('INACTIVE','A1')
INSERT INTO #temptable VALUES ('INACTIVE','B1')
INSERT INTO #temptable VALUES ('INACTIVE','B1')

SELECT ISNULL(a2.[status],'INACTIVE') as 'Custom', a1.[status], a1.[name]
FROM #temptable as a1
LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM #temptable 
        WHERE [status] = 'ACTIVE'
        ) as a2 on a1.[name] = a2.[name]    

DROP TABLE #temptable
```

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but I'm connecting to an Oracle server. This didn't work for me--I don't think I have access to create temp tables.

Comment: The temp table was just a stand in for your table. You should be able to replace the two cases of #temptable with your table name in the SELECT statement and only run that part.

Comment: @tpet yes but the code needs to also be corrected. You have some missing statement terminators (SQL Server is probably the only DBMS that allows this - and only in some cases), the `ISNULL()` function shoudl be replaced with either `NVL()` or the standard `COALESCE()` and the proprietary brackets have to be removed or replaced, too.